# Get all() data and order by Ascending order and select

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

i want to get all user data and sort by ascending order then select required columns

```
$drivers = Driver::all()
         ->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
        ->get();
```

now i'm getting all the data

thank you

Comment: [Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, remove `all()` and add an `orderBy()`:

```
    $drivers = Driver::select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
    ->orderBy('the-order-column', 'asc or desc')
    ->get();
```

The methods `all()` and `get()` do the same thing, except from that you can't modify the query using `all()` (like adding `orderBy()`).

Laravels documentation on `orderBy()`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 1):

To sort results, just use [OrderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

For example, if you want to sort by first_name, use :

```
$drivers = Driver::select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_id')
         ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
         ->get();
```

change 'asc' with 'desc' if you want descending order.

And don't use `All()` if you don't want everything.